# AWS Dynamodb Scan | Scan if exists column values

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a table that has a column called "items", but not all rows have it, so I want to scan all rows that have "items".

Something like:

```
$resposta = $clientDB->scan(array(
    'TableName' => 'tableName',
    'Key' => [
        'items' => ['S' => 'exists']
    ]
));
```

But I can't figure out how to do it...

The table has 10000 rows, but only 10 of them have "items", and I want to get only these 10 rows.

**Edit:**

As Seth Geoghegan pointed below, it was necessary create a global secondary indexes on the attribute i wanted to filter.

I ended up here:

```
    $params = [
        'TableName' => 'tableName',
        'FilterExpression' => "attribute_exists(items)"
    ];
```

OR

```
    $params = [
        'TableName' => 'tableName',
        'FilterExpression' => 'items != :null',
        'ExpressionAttributeValues' =>  [
            ':null' => null,
        ],
    ];
```

But both didnt worked... First one seens necessary ExpressionAttributeValues to be setup and the second the php stop working with no error logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after some effort, i found a way though:

```
    $resposta = $clientDB->scan(array(
        'TableName' => 'tableName',
        'FilterExpression' => "attribute_exists(items)"
    ));
```

After i created another global secondary index (GSI) for "items" (pointed by Seth Geoghegan), i just needed to add in the scan function the FilterExpression the "attribute_exists(items") and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

This is a perfect use case for global secondary indexes (GSI)!

You can create a GSI on the `items` attribute.  Items with the `items` attribute defined will get projected into the GSI. Importantly, items that do *not* contain this attribute will *not* be in the index.  You could then query the GSI and retrieve the items you're after.

Comment: i will try that and see if's gonna work